# What is the meaning of 'd?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

> Man: Now Carly, that's my older daughter, has just had her seventh birthday, so presumably she[**'d**] be in a different group?

Could anybody tell me the meaning of **'d** and the usage of it?

Comment: It's a contraction of *had* or *would*.

Comment: @Robusto Would you tell me, in this situation, that is **would** or **had** and exactly the usage of it?

Comment: More generally, the meaning of an apostrophe is that it replaces one or more letters. In this case, it replaces the "woul" of "would". Most commonly, it reflects a "weakened" pronunciation of a following word, so that what was formerly a separate word becomes a suffix of the previous word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using 2 contractions in the Post:

> that's == "that is"
> she'd == "she would" (in this Particular case; In other context it can be "she had")

There is no space in the contractions.

Situation to Explain the Sentence:
Imagine that School girls are being put in groups according to age. Carly wants to be in the same group as her cousin, who is 6 years old. Since Carly has become 7 years old recently, her father is asking the teacher whether Carly "would" be in a Different group or whether she and her cousin "would" be considered the same age group.

Here are more about contractions:
https://www.grammarly.com/blog/contractions/
https://www.thoughtco.com/contractions-commonly-used-informal-english-1692651
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/contractions
https://www.masterclass.com/articles/contraction-grammar-guide

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Actually It is *be*. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says, it's a contraction of "she had [been] [in a different group]".

Comment: Actually It is *be*. Sorry about that.

Comment: @fool2951  …presumably she'd [she **would**] be in a different group. It's: I / you / he / she / he / it / we / you / they **would** ***be***.